# How to get ICredential of running user in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

How do I get an ICredential object within my web application?

- I use Windows Authentication

I tried using the following code:

```
WindowsImpersonationContext securityContext = 
      Request.LogonUserIdentity.Impersonate();
```

After the last line of code both: **CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials and CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials are still empty**.

I know that the identity is right because the following property shows the right domain\user account I'm using:
`Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` => "domain\user"

This is the authentication type of that object:

`Request.LogonUserIdentity.AuthenticationType` => "NTLM"

Answer (score 2):

In order to get an ICredential implementation of the user, you first need to get a hold of the WindowsIdentity for the user (e.g. through [Page.User.Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.identity(v=VS.100).aspx)). With the WindowsIdentity object you can [impersonate](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158) the user.  After successful impersonation you can get a hold of the credentials for the user through [CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx).

The question now is, what do you want to do with the credentials?  If you want to use those credentials to access some ressource on a different server you'd probably have to have Keberos delegation enabled to allow the server hop.  I wouldn't know how to do that :-)

Comment: I tried this approach, but I still have the CredentialCache empty (I've updated the post with the code I used)

Comment: Did you put <identity impersonate="true" /> in web.config?  I don't know if it matters.  Maybe it not possible to impersonate in this way for in an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you need it for?

You can retrieve the username from System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity